# How to retrieve a single YouTube playlist and display all its top 10 video titles using API v3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube-data-api

How to retrieve a single YouTube playlist and display all its titles using API v3?

What I am getting already is the video title but without playlist.
Anyone share some query if there is one I'm missing.
My requirement is a single YouTube playlist video title.

Now i'm getting all channel video titles. What is missing?

```js
var channelname = 'mipaltan';

$(document).ready(function () {
    $.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels", {
        part: 'contentDetails',
        forUsername: 'mipaltan',
        key: 'AIzaSyCT8kXaxJ2l29vYg4HBdYy36H-PhAH-Teg'
    },
      function (data) {
          $.each(data.items, function (i, item) {
              pid = item.contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads;
              getVids(pid);
          })
      }
    );

    function getVids(pid) {
        $.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems", {
            part: 'snippet',
            maxResults: 10,
            playlistId: pid,
            key: 'AIzaSyCT8kXaxJ2l29vYg4HBdYy36H-PhAH-Teg'
        },

          function (data) {
              $.each(data.items, function (i, item) {
                  vidsTitle = item.snippet.title;
                  output = '<li>' + vidsTitle + '</li>';
                  // Append to results 
                  $('#results').append(output);
              })
          }
        );
    }
});
```

```html
   <title> Get Video Title</title>
<style>
body {
      background: #f4f4f4;
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 14px;
      color: #666;
    }
    #container {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      overflow: auto;
      margin: auto;
      padding: 5px;
    }
     #container2 {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      overflow: auto;
      margin: auto;
      padding: 15px;
    }
</style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    <script>
       function newSrc(testurl) {
           document.getElementById("MyFrame").src = testurl;
       }
   </script>
    </head>   
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div id="container2"></div>
  <iframe id="MyFrame"; width="220"; height="160"; src="http://www.youtube.com/embed?listType=playlist&list=PLVB7Pe64pVdd0RwAOTy7K4pm7TMAK1fQq"   frameborder="0" allowfullscreen ></iframe>
             <div style="padding-left:5px", id="result" class ="footer-widget"> </div>
    <div id="container">
       <ul id="results"></ul>
    </div>
  </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any issues in your code.

In order to view the playlist you need to hit the playlist button, which brings up the playlist thumbnails.

[Please see the attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMm58.jpg)

Comment: Thanks for you time Anish, one thing you see Playlist Video title and in bottom title both are different. i want to playlist title and bottom title is same but now is different ,i want are both same.

Comment: again i just go through the code and I found that playlist id that return from the request is not matched with id on the iframe.

please change the 
playlistId: pid,
to
playlistId: "PLVB7Pe64pVdd0RwAOTy7K4pm7TMAK1fQq",
on getVids function